# Removing brackets from list of anagrams

Tags: java

I have problem with removing brackets

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        getAnagrams(new InputStreamReader(new URL("http://www.puzzlers.org/pub/wordlists/unixdict.txt").openStream(),
                StandardCharsets.UTF_8)).forEach(System.out::println);
    }

    private static String canonicalize(String string) {
        return Stream.of(string.split("")).sorted().collect(Collectors.joining());
    }

    public static List<Set<String>> getAnagrams(Reader rr) {
        Map<String, Set<String>> mapa = new BufferedReader(rr).lines().flatMap(Pattern.compile("\\W+")::splitAsStream)
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Main::canonicalize, Collectors.toSet()));
        return mapa.values().stream().filter(lista -> lista.size() > 1).collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
}
```

The output is

> [hamster, amherst]
>       [genital, gelatin]

and it should be

> hamster amherst
>      genital gelatin

Answer (score 2):

You are just printing out your sets, you have getAngarams() that will return List of Sets of Strings, there are many ways to get raw elements without brackets, one of the possibilities is iterator:

Replace your:

```
getAnagrams(new InputStreamReader(new URL("http://www.puzzlers.org/pub/wordlists/unixdict.txt").openStream(),
        StandardCharsets.UTF_8)).forEach(System.out::println);
```

with:

```
 getAnagrams(new InputStreamReader(new URL("http://www.puzzlers.org/pub/wordlists/unixdict.txt").openStream(),
            StandardCharsets.UTF_8)).iterator().forEachRemaining(x -> {for (String s : x) System.out.print(s + " ");
        System.out.println();});
```

Answer (score 1):

It is because `forEach(System.out::println)` calls the `toString()` method inside `Set` calss.

Add this method to your class

```
public static void println(Set<String> items) {
    for (String item : items) {
        System.out.print(item + " ");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

and replace that code `forEach(System.out::println)` with `forEach(Main::println)`

---

or by using this instead of adding new method:

```
getAnagrams(new InputStreamReader(new URL("http://www.puzzlers.org/pub/wordlists/unixdict.txt").openStream(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8))
            .forEach(items -> {
                for (String item : items) {
                    System.out.print(item + " ");
                }
                System.out.println();
            });
```

Comment: No need to make additional method, he can just make a change to his lambda.

Comment: Yes, Thank you for it.