# Sorting map alphabetical

Tags: java

[Removing brackets from list of anagrams](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47741204/removing-brackets-from-list-of-anagrams/47754675#47754675)

Hello, i have been asked to create new question insted of asking again in the same thread.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    getAnagrams(new InputStreamReader(new URL("http://www.puzzlers.org/pub/wordlists/unixdict.txt").openStream(),
            StandardCharsets.UTF_8)).forEach(items -> {
                for (String item : items) {
                    System.out.print(item + " ");
                }
                System.out.println();
            });
}
private static String canonicalize(String string) {

    return Stream.of(string.split("")).sorted().collect(Collectors.joining());
}

public static List<Set<String>> getAnagrams(Reader rr) {
Map<String, Set<String>> mapa = (Map<String, Set<String>>) new BufferedReader(rr).lines()
                                 .flatMap(Pattern.compile("\\W+")::splitAsStream)
                                 .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Main::canonicalize, Collectors.toSet()));
    return mapa.values().stream().filter(lista -> lista.size() > 4).collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

}

How do i sort my output like "evil levi live veil vile"? Cuz for now i have "veil evil vile levi live"

UPDATE
Last thing is to sort output alphabeticaly

For now = "evil levi live veil vile, abel able bale bela elba"

Needed = "abel able bale bela elba, evil levi live veil vile"

Comment: What do you want to sort, the list of sets or the sets inside the list? If the sets then use a sorted set (e.g. `TreeSet`).

Comment: The other possibility is to sort the values and then collect them into a `Set` which **retains insertion order**, like `LinkedHashSet`. However the set will then not hold the data sorted if you later add elements. For this you will need **sorted** data-structures. Among the `Set`s the `TreeSet` would be a good candidate. Of course the sorting is **not for free**. Operations that need to search elements, like `contains`, `add`, `remove` etc. *only* run in `O(log n)` and not in `O(1)` (like in `HashSet`).

Answer (score 2):

Here's the easiest way I can think of

```
return mapa.values().stream()
    .filter(lista -> lista.size() > 4)
    .map(set -> new TreeSet<>(set))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

`TreeSet` keeps its elements sorted.

Comment: Just as a note, you could replace the lambda in `map` by a method reference `TreeSet::new`.

Comment: You can use `new` as a method reference? Wow, I did not know that.

Comment: Yup, there are plenty of cool method references. You can even cast using references `String.class::cast`. Or `String.class::isInstance` for `x instanceOf String` and so on.